# Projective Transformations on Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, projective-geometry

Let P be a polynomial in $\Bbb{RP}^2$. (It doesn't have to be in 2 dimensions, but assume it for clarity and simplicity)

For example: $P=3x^2+6y^2-7xy+10y-1$

Now, let's perform a projective transformation, $f$, on it.

$$f(x,y)=\left(\frac{a_1x+b_1y+c_1}{a_3x+b_3y+c_3},\frac{a_2x+b_2y+c_2}{a_3x+b_3y+c_3}\right)$$

Then it turns out that $f(P)=Q$ where Q is a polynomial of the same degree:

$$deg(P)=deg(Q)$$

I completely understand the cases where $deg(P)\le2$.

I have no idea why this is true when the degree is larger than 2. I'd appreciate a clear explanation for why this happens (if it does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing your example in homogeneous coordinates, we get

$$P(x,y,z) = 3x^2 + 6y^2 - 7xy + 10yz - 1z^2$$

which has equal degree in all terms. The transformation in homogeneous coordinates would be

$$f:v\mapsto Mv=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3
\end{pmatrix}v$$

Now if you plug a transformed point into your original curve, you have

$$P(M\cdot(x,y,z)^T) = 3(a_1x + b_1y + c_1z)^2 + 6(a_2x+b_2y+c_2z)^2 - 7(a_1x + b_1y + c_1z)(a_2x+b_2y+c_2z) + \cdots$$

Now every term of the original curve becomes a constant times a product of parentheses, where the number of parentheses (taking powers into account) equals the degree. Expanding them using the distributive law you get a homogeneous polynomial whose degree again equals the original degree. So degree is preserved by all of this.

Well, plugging the *transformed* point into the *original* curve is essentially the wrong direction: it will give you a description of the inversely transformed curve. But to fix that, you simply invert the transformation matrix, without affecting the degree arguments stated above.

Comment: Even though this didn't exactly explain what I was missing, what you said did help me understand, so thanks. What I think I needed to see was in a definition of a projective function as an affine transformation followed by drawing a line through the center (0,0,0) and seeing where the line intersects the z=1 plane. What I didn't see was that because the polynomial is homogeneous, a line through (0,0,0) either only intersects the polynomial in (0,0,0), or intersects it in every point on the line - which explains why it's enough to take the polynomial and not find each point separately.